# Batch processing mode in Caffe

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'd like to use the Caffe library to extract image features but I'm having performance issues. I can only use the CPU mode. I was told Caffe supported batch processing mode, in which the average time required to process one image was much slower.

I'm calling the following method:

```
const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& 
Net::Forward(const vector<Blob<Dtype>* > & bottom, Dtype* loss = NULL);
```

and I'm putting in a vector of size 1, containing a single blob of the following dimensions - (num: 10, channels: 3, width: 227, height: 227). It represents a single image oversampled in the same way as in the official python wrapper.

This works and gives correct results. It is, however, too slow.

Whenever I try to send in a vector containing more than one blob (of the same dimensions), I get the following error:

> F0910 16:10:14.848492 15615 blob.cpp:355] Trying to copy blobs of different sizes.
>   Check failure stack trace:

How do I make Caffe process my images in a batch?

Comment: if you input a blob with `num=10` what is the size of the output you get? does `Net::Forward` averages the features over the 10 inputs for you??

Comment: No, the output blob is of size 10 x 4096. I then average the values myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to feed larger batches you need the first (and only) blob in `bottom` to have `num>10`. Feeding a blob with `num=20` is the same as feeding two inputs with `oversample=10`. You will, of course, have to perform the averaging manually according to the `oversampling` you are using.

Furthermore, you might want to change the first input dimension in your `deploy.prototxt` file from 10 to some larger value (depending on your machine's memory capacity)

Comment: So, in other words, there's no way to process a batch of images, without altering the definition of the network, correct? Because the network definition starts like this (the input blob dimensions are hardcoded there): 

name: "CaffeNet"
input: "data"
input_dim: 10
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227
layers {
...

Comment: @DušanRychnovský the network definition is used for memory allocation. You can change this "on the fly" using `Reshape`

Comment: Got it, thanks! :) It is confusing to me, though, that the signature of the Forward method expects a *vector* of blobs. What's the reason behind that if you can only ever feed vectors of size one?

Comment: @DušanRychnovský some networks has more than one `"bottom"`, therefore you need a vector entry per `"bottom"`...